# How to call a instance method having paramters in same class in the following code

Tags: android

Implemented onItemclick() for listview , Want to use same functionality for another button outside from listview,if it dont have parameters then we can call directly with name ,but here is my code how to do it,.Thnaks.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        System.out.println(path
                + myList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        // String newpath = path + myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Uri data = Uri.parse(path + myList.getItemAtPosition(position));
        if (mp.mediaPlayer != null) {
            mp.mediaPlayer.stop();
            mp.mediaPlayer.reset();
            mp.mediaPlayer.release();
            mp.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    data);
            mp.mediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            mp.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    data);
            mp.mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access onItemClick() parameters in button onClick(). if thats the case try like this..

Declare these global

```
AdapterView aView;
View v;
int pos;
```

and assign them in onItemClick()

```
aView = arg0;
v = arg1;
pos = position;
```

and use them in button click..